# Spring boot : JQuery validation not working when @Path Variable is used

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I am new to Spring boot and trying to work my way through my first Spring boot app. I am using Spring Tool Suite as my IDE.

In the app im creating, the user should be able to edit a specific record after viewing it. im using path variable annotation to get the ID from the jsp that im viewing the record to the jsp im using to edit the record. I have used JQuery for front end validation and i have noted that the JQuery validation works everywhere except in the places i have used path variable.

I have searched everywhere to find a solution, but can't seem to find any that successfully addresses this.

Here is my Controller

```
`package com.example.demo.controller;

import java.util.List;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.mail.MailException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes;

import com.example.demo.dao.FaultDao;
import com.example.demo.dao.Technician_faultDao;
import com.example.demo.model.Fault;
//import com.example.demo.model.Technicianfault;
import com.example.demo.model.Technicianfault;

@Controller
public class FaultController {

@Autowired
public FaultDao faultdao;

@RequestMapping(value="/detail",method=RequestMethod.GET)   
public ModelAndView view(){  
    List<Fault> list=faultdao.getAllFaults();
    return new ModelAndView("viewdetails.jsp","list",list);  
} 
@RequestMapping("editfault")
public String editform() {
    return "editfault.jsp";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/editfault/{faultid}",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String edit(@PathVariable int faultid, ModelMap model) {

    Fault fault= faultdao.getFaultById(faultid);
    model.addAttribute("edfault", fault);
    return "/editfault";
}

/* It updates record for the given id in editfault page and redirects to /detail */  
 @RequestMapping(value="/editsave",method = RequestMethod.POST)  
    public ModelAndView editsave(@Valid @ModelAttribute("edfault") Fault fau,BindingResult result, Model model){  
        System.out.println("id is"+fau.getId());

        //if ( result.hasErrors()) {
            //return new ModelAndView("form");
        //}
        faultdao.update(fau);  
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/detail");  
    } `
```

FaultDao.java

```
package com.example.demo.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.ResultSetExtractor;
import org.springframework.mail.MailException;
import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.demo.model.Fault;
import com.example.demo.model.Technicianfault;

@Service
public class FaultDao {

JdbcTemplate template;
private JavaMailSender mailsender;

@Autowired
public void setTemplate(JdbcTemplate template, JavaMailSender mailsender ) {  
    this.template = template;  
    this.mailsender=mailsender;
}  

@Autowired
public void setDataSource(DataSource datasource) {

    template= new JdbcTemplate(datasource);
}

public Fault getFaultById(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 return template.query("select * from fault where jobID="+id+"",new ResultSetExtractor<Fault>(){  
                     public Fault extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException,  
                            DataAccessException {  


                         Fault e=new Fault();  
                        while(rs.next()){  

                            e.setId(rs.getInt(1));  
                            e.setNature(rs.getString(2));  
                            e.setPriority(rs.getString(3));  
                            e.setStatus(rs.getString(4));
                            e.setCategory(rs.getString(5));
                            e.setCliID(rs.getInt(6));
                            e.setBrID(rs.getInt(7));  
                            e.setDescrip(rs.getString(8));
                            e.setReportedBy(rs.getString(9));
                            e.setFixedBy(rs.getDate(10));
                            e.setReportedOn(rs.getDate(11));
                            e.setIsassigned(rs.getBoolean(12));
                        }  
                        return e;  
                        }  
                    });  
            }

public void update(Fault p) {
        String sql="update fault set nature='"+p.getNature()+"',priority='"+p.getPriority()+"',status='"+p.getStatus()+"',category='"+p.getCategory()+"',cID='"+p.getCliID()+"',brID='"+p.getBrID()+"',descrip='"+p.getDescrip()+"' ,reportedBy='"+p.getReportedBy()+"', fixedby='"+p.getFixedBy()+"',reportedDate='"+p.getReportedOn()+"' where jobID="+p.getId()+"";
        System.out.println(sql);
       template.update(sql);  
    }
```

EditFault.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ page isELIgnored = "false" %>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"  %>   
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/custom.css">

<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/proper.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrapValidator.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"></script>

<title>Edit Fault Details</title>

</head>

<body>
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="edfault" id="validateEdForm" class="form-horizontal" action="/editsave">

        <div class="form-group row" style="margin-left: 30%;margin-top: 4%">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="id">Job ID</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                F${edfault.id} 

                        <form:input type="hidden" path="id" class="form-control" id="id" name="id"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

    <div class="form-group row" style="margin-left: 30%;margin-top: 4%">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="nature">Nature</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <form:input type="text" path="nature" class="form-control" id="nature" name="nature"/>
                        <div class = "has-error">
                        <form:errors path="nature" class="help-inline"/>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


            <div class="form-group row"  style="margin-left: 30%;margin-top: 2%">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="category">Category</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4"> 
                        <select style="width: 280px; height: 35px;padding: 8px" id="category" path="category" name="category">
                        <option value="${edfault.category}">${edfault.category}</option>
                        <option value="Hardware">Hardware</option>
                        <option value="Software">Software</option>
                        <option value="Firewall">Firewall</option>
                        </select>
                        <div class = "has-error">
                        <form:errors path="category" class="help-inline"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row" style="margin-left: 30%;margin-top: 2%">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="priority">Priority :</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <select style="width: 280px; height: 35px;padding: 8px" id="priority" path="priority" name="priority">
                        <option value="${edfault.priority}">${edfault.priority}</option>
                        <option value="Urgent">Urgent</option>
                        <option value="Not Urgent">Not Urgent</option>
                        </select>
                        <div class = "has-error">
                        <form:errors path="priority" class="help-inline"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row" style="margin-left: 30%;margin-top: 2%">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="cliID">Client Name :</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <select style="width: 280px; height: 35px;padding: 8px" id="cliID" path="cliID" name="cliID">
                        <option value="${edfault.cliID}">${edfault.cliID}</option>

                        <%

                            try{

                                String sql = "select clientID, name from client";
                                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/automatedbarcode_database?useSSL=false", "root", "root");
                                Statement stm = con.createStatement();
                                ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(sql);

                                while (rs.next()){

                                    %>

                                    <option value="<%= rs.getInt("clientID")%>"> <%= rs.getString("name") %></option>
                                    <%
                                }

                            }

                            catch(Exception e){

                                e.printStackTrace();
                                out.println("Error : " + e.getMessage());
                            }

                        %>

                        </select>
                        <div class = "has-error">
                        <form:errors path="cliID" class="help-inline"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row"  style="margin-left: 30%;margin-top: 2%">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="brID">Branch Name :</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4"> 
                    <select style="width: 280px; height: 35px;padding: 8px" id="brID" path="brID" name="brID">
                        <option value="${edfault.brID}">${edfault.brID}</option>

                        <%

                            try{

                                String sql = "select branchID, Bcity from branch";
                                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/automatedbarcode_database?useSSL=false", "root", "root");
                                Statement stm = con.createStatement();
                                ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(sql);

                                while (rs.next()){

                                    %>

                                    <option value="<%= rs.getInt("branchID")%>"> <%= rs.getString("Bcity") %></option>
                                    <%
                                }

                            }

                            catch(Exception e){

                                e.printStackTrace();
                                out.println("Error : " + e.getMessage());
                            }

                        %>

                        </select>

                        <div class = "has-error">
                        <form:errors path="brID" class="help-inline"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>

            <div class="form-group row"  style="margin-left: 30%;margin-top: 2%">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="descrip">Description  :</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4"> 
                        <form:input type="text" path="descrip" class="form-control" id="descrip" name="descrip"/>
                        <div class = "has-error">
                        <form:errors path="descrip" class="help-inline"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row"  style="margin-left: 30%;margin-top: 2%">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="reportedBy">Reported By  :</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4"> 
                        <form:input type="text" path="reportedBy" class="form-control" id="reportedBy" name="reportedBy"/>
                        <div class = "has-error">
                        <form:errors path="reportedBy" class="help-inline"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row"  style="margin-left: 30%;margin-top: 2%">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="fixedBy">Fixed By  : </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4"> 
                        <form:input type="date" path="fixedBy" class="form-control" id="fixedBy" name="fixedBy"/>
                        <div class = "has-error">
                        <form:errors path="fixedBy" class="help-inline"/>
                    </div>
            </div></div>
            <div class="form-group row"  style="margin-left: 30%;margin-top: 2%">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="reportedOn">Reported On  : </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4"> 
                        <form:input type="date" path="reportedOn" class="form-control" id="reportedOn" name="reportedOn"/>
                        <div class = "has-error">
                        <form:errors path="reportedOn" class="help-inline"/>
                    </div>
            </div></div>

            <div class="form-group row" style="margin-left: 30%;margin-top: 2%">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="status">Status</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <select style="width: 280px; height: 35px;padding: 8px" id="status" path="status" name="status">
                        <option value="${edfault.status}">${edfault.status}</option>
                        <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
                        <option value="Completed">Completed</option>
                        </select>
                        <div class = "has-error">
                        <form:errors path="status" class="help-inline"/>
                    </div>
   </div>
            </div>
                <br><br><br><br>    
        <div class="form-group" style="margin-left: 42%;margin-top: 2%"> 
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <div class="form-actions">
                    <button type="submit" value = "edit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
                    <button type="reset" value="reset" class="btn btn-warning">Reset</button>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>

</form:form>

</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){
        var dtToday = new Date();

        var month = dtToday.getMonth() + 1;
        var day = dtToday.getDate();
        var year = dtToday.getFullYear();
        if(month < 10)
            month = '0' + month.toString();
        if(day < 10)
            day = '0' + day.toString();

        var maxDate = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
        //alert(maxDate);
        $('#reportedOn').attr('max', maxDate);
    });

    $(function(){
        var dtToday = new Date();

        var month = dtToday.getMonth() + 1;
        var day = dtToday.getDate();
        var year = dtToday.getFullYear();
        if(month < 10)
            month = '0' + month.toString();
        if(day < 10)
            day = '0' + day.toString();

        var minDate = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
        //alert(maxDate);
        $('#fixedBy').attr('min', minDate);
    });

            $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#validateEdForm').bootstrapValidator({
                feedbackIcons: {
                    valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                    invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                    validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
                },
                fields: {

                    nature: {
                        validators: {
                            stringLength: {
                                min: 5,
                                message: 'Enter nature of fault reported with minimum of 5 letters length'
                            },

                            notEmpty: {
                                message: 'Nature field is required'
                            }
                        }
                    },

                    category: {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: 'Category field is required'
                            }
                        }
                    },

                    priority: {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: 'Priority field is required'
                            }
                        }
                    },

                    cliID: {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: 'Client Name field is required'
                            }
                        }
                    },

                    brID: {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: 'Branch Name field is required'
                            }
                        }
                    },


                    descrip: {
                        validators: {
                            stringLength: {
                                min: 10,
                                message: 'Description should be at least 10 letters long'
                            },
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: 'Description field is required'
                            },

                            regexp:{
                                    regexp: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+$/,
                                    message: 'Description can only have letters, numbers, dots and underscores'
                            }
                        }
                    },

                    reportedBy: {
                        validators: {
                            stringLength: {
                                min: 5,
                                message: 'Name of the person reporting on behalf of client should be at least 5 letters long'
                            },

                            notEmpty: {
                                message: 'Reported By field is required'
                            }
                        }
                    },

                    fixedBy: {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: 'Fixed By field is required'
                            }
                        }
                    },

                    reportedOn: {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: 'Reported on field is required'
                            }
                        }
                    },

                    status: {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: 'Status field is required'
                            }
                        }
                    },

                    }
                });
            });

        </script>
</body>
```

And here is my POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>Project</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Project</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
     <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
     <version>8.5.31</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-mail -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
 <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
 <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
<artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
<version>5.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>

</dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


</project>
```

The Jquery validation was working perfectly fine before i used @Path variable to get the id from the URI. Please help me!
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. You just need to add / in front of the script src paths in the jsp.

```
<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/js/proper.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/bootstrapValidator.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"></script>
```